# Binary bits in my blade template - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am rescuing information from a database and deploying a blade type template in laravel. The problem I have is that binary digits appear, without having placed them, I really do not know what may be happening. This is my blade template:

```
@extends('plantillas.mireporte')
@section('cabecerareporte')
@endsection
@section('cuerporeporte')
<p class="display h6 text-uppercase text-center">{{$titulo}} </p>
  <div class="container-fluid mx-4">
     <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 ">
          <table class="table">
            <tbody>
              <tr class="table-active ">  
                @foreach($lista as $e)
                  <td class="text-uppercase text-white bg-danger">{{ $e }} 
               </td>
                @endforeach
              </tr> 

              @foreach($DATOS as $item)

              @if($bandera==0)
                <tr class="table-active ">

              @foreach($lista as $list)
                  <td>{{$item->$list}}</td>
              @endforeach
              {{$bandera=1}}
                </tr>
              @else
                <tr class="bg-white text-dark">

              @foreach($lista as $list)
                  <td>{{$item->$list}}</td>
              @endforeach
              {{$bandera=0}}
                </tr>
              @endif

              @endforeach 
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <footer>

</footer>
@endsection
```

This is what appears to me:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7osT.jpg

I really do not know what it could be, analyze the labels and they are all closed.

Comment: Este sitio es solamente para preguntas en ingles. Si no lo puedes traducir, es mejor que encuentres otro sitio para ayudas en castellano.

Comment: It's already translated

Comment: where are they appearing?

Comment: Try commenting each of the `@foreach` one by one, are you able to find the problem?

Comment: I have attached an image with the problem of binary digits.

Comment: I just commented on each one of the @foreach one by one, and the binary digits disappeared, but why is this?

Comment: {{$bandera=1}} will execute and print while \@php ... \@endphp will execute only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
{{$bandera=1}}
```

to

```
@php $bandera=1; @endphp
```

and this

```
{{$bandera=0}}
```

to

```
@php $bandera=0; @endphp
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade

Comment: Shorter version would be `@php($bandera=1)`.